# How can I get the target table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

### The table look like this

```
number      day amount
013xxxxxxxx 1   62773
013xxxxxxxx 8   52963
013xxxxxxxx 9   10810
013xxxxxxxx 10  84193
013xxxxxxxx 11  91791
019xxxxxxxx 1   89055
019xxxxxxxx 3   85366
019xxxxxxxx 5   47318
```

- In the above table. It is source table. Here we can see all the day number is not available. So I need to add those unavailable rows with amount **0**.

### I want the table like this.

```
number      day amount
013xxxxxxxx 1   62773
013xxxxxxxx 2   0
013xxxxxxxx 3   0
013xxxxxxxx 4   0
013xxxxxxxx 5   0
013xxxxxxxx 6   0
013xxxxxxxx 7   0
013xxxxxxxx 8   52963
013xxxxxxxx 9   10810
013xxxxxxxx 10  84193
013xxxxxxxx 11  91791
019xxxxxxxx 1   89055
019xxxxxxxx 2   0
019xxxxxxxx 3   85366
019xxxxxxxx 4   0
019xxxxxxxx 5   47318
```

Comment: Why did you use the **Oracle** tag? Do you use PostgreSQL (as the title suggests), or both, or what?

Comment: my mistake,.... I have edited the post... I need for postgres only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this query ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyiRy8hWHfLteuYZMQQxyW/0))

```
with x as (SELECT distinct test.number,generated_day FROM generate_series(1, 31) as generated_day, test),
y as (SELECT distinct test.number, MAX(day) OVER (PARTITION BY number) AS max_day FROM test)
select x.number,x.generated_day,coalesce(t.amount,0)
from x left join test t on t."number" = x.number and t.day = x.generated_day
where x.generated_day <= (SELECT MAX(day) max_day FROM test where test.number = x.number) 
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works like a champ....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a calendar table approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT number, MIN(day) AS min_day, MAX(day) AS max_day
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY number
)

SELECT n.number, s.day, COALESCE(t2.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM yourTable) n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 31)) AS s(day)
INNER JOIN cte 
    ON t.number = n.number
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.number = n.number AND t2.day = s.day
WHERE s.day BETWEEN t.min_day AND t.max_day
ORDER BY n.number, s.day;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "s"¶  Position: 324`

Comment: @BackstreetImrul I fixed it, tough question, check the demo.